# Jquery call to Controller of MVC: ReferenceError: url is not defined

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I tried all my efforts, but just can't understand where the error lies. I searched the google also but did not find any good solution. It is not actually calling the controller/action in mvc. The same is running good in the other parts of the project.

I have a contrller "RB" under a folder "MVC", the action is defined as "SS".
and I am firing following code from my javascript file :

```
var sSch = function (request, response) {
        var t = request.RF.substring(0, 1);
        var d = new Date(request.RNR);            
        $.ajax({
            url: "/MVC/RB/SS",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                _rId: request.ReportId,
                _date: d.toString(),
                _fcy: t
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert('Success');

            },
            error:  function (data) {
                alert('Error');

            }
        });
    };
```

I am calling this function onClick of a button and properly getting the values in Request variable, but it is not anyhow calling the Controller/Action there.
On firebug I tested it throws the exception "ReferenceError: url is not defined". I am using MVC3 under VS 2010.

Please Help.

Comment: Doesn't seem like there is anything wrong with this code. Are you sure this is where the error is thrown?

Comment: build your solution and try again

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your action properly instead of

```
 url: "/MVC/RB/SS",
```

use

```
 url:  @Url.Action("SS", "RB")
```

Comment: In case your script is in a separate file you should place the result of `@Url.Action("SS", "RB")` into a hidden field or data-attribute of a field in your view. That way you can get to it in the script.

Comment: Hi,I tried the following:  url: "@Action('/MVC/RB/SS')", Returns the same error ....

Answer (score 0):

For the url you have 'MVC/RB/SS' this is relative to your current directory a quick test would be to put in  url: "../MVC/RB/SS" or  url: "../../MVC/RB/SS" depending on how deep you page is in the site structure.

Another way would be to try this:

```
 url: "@Action("/MVC/RB/SS")",
```

this will create the correct url at the correct level for you and should be picked up.

Comment: Hi,I tried the following:  url: "@Action('/MVC/RB/SS')", Returns the same error

Comment: I tried with ref url also like var urlaction= AP.rootDir + "RB/SS"; and then I passed it as url : urlaction, the result is same. although urlaction returns the "/mvc/RB/SS"

Comment: Have you changed any of your routing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
url: "~/MVC/RB/SS",
```

This will resolve to path "http://site-name/MVC/RB/SS".

What does Firebug say?